# GoodData - fixed value over time

Tags: business-intelligence, gooddata, maql

Is it possible to carry one last value in time (T2) over to previous times? In Tableau I would use LOD "FIXED" expression..

I already tried all the PARENT filters WITH/WITHOUT EXCEPT.. Nothing works..

Input:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| T-1 | 7 |
| T0 | 8 |
| T1 | 9 |
| T2 | 10 |

Wanted output:

| Time | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T-1 | 7 | 10 |
| T0 | 8 | 10 |
| T1 | 9 | 10 |
| T2 | 10 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use *BY ALL OTHER* / *BY ALL OTHER EXCEPT* expressions to lock the aggregation on a certain level.

In your case the metric would be something like:
*SELECT MAX(VALUE) BY ALL OTHER*

Documentation can be found here:
https://help.gooddata.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=86795434